# Commit insert command per each 1 million rows

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, query-optimization, sql-insert

I have a table tbl_1 (in oracle database) with more than 1 billion records. I want to insert all the records in a new table tbl_2.
If I use:

```
insert into tbl_2 select * from tbl-1;
commit;
```

then the code takes a long time to done because oracle DBMS must consider online redo log files and zero data loss.

An idea is to commit insert per each 1 million records therefor online redo log files handling and other background processes applied by DBMS take less time. An answer is using cursor but I guess using cursor makes the code slow. Do you have any idea?

Comment: How about export/import?

Comment: Committing more frequently will actually *increase* the amount of time spent writing to redo logs and syncing control files.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I need to use insert-commit every day in a scheduled job. in other hand, I do not have any access to or permission on the OS. I just have access in schema level. For using exported file I need to access on the OS.

Comment: Dear pmdba, you are right. but notice when records go numerous, committing may has more advantage than disadvantages you said. on the other hand, using commit was just a suggestion that I never test its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=issue-frequent-commit-statements#4959613293151):

> There is only one thing that dicates when you commit -- when is your transaction complete? Then you commit, period.

and

> Frequently commiting in the mistaken belief that you are conserving resources or making things go faster only does this for you:
>
> - slows you down, yes, that is right, SLOWS YOU DOWN -- makes you run SLOOOWWWWEEERRR
> - doesn't conserve any resources, in fact, it consumes more (you generate MORE redo)
> - seriously puts into question the integrity of your data

and (earlier in that thread):

> Frequent commits -- sure, "frees up" that undo -- which invariabley leads to ORA-1555 and the failure of your process. Thats good for performance right?
>
> Frequent commits -- sure, "frees up" locks -- which throws transactional integrity out the window. Thats great for data integrity right?
>
> Frequent commits -- sure "frees up" redo log buffer space -- by forcing you to WAIT for a sync write to the file system every time -- you WAIT and WAIT and WAIT. I can see how that would "increase performance" (NOT). Oh yeah, the fact that the redo buffer is flushed in the background
>
> - every three seconds
> - when 1/3 full
> - when 1meg full
>   would do the same thing (free up this resource) AND not make you wait.
>
> frequent commits -- there is NO resource to free up
> ... etc.

A single big insert and single commit will be the fastest option.

There might be things you can do to speed things up a bit, such as disabling constraints and triggers, dropping indexes and recreating after the insert, direct-path inserts, etc. but it depends on how you have things set up now.

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for your answer. in a week ahead, I test this idea for a table with 500 millions records and publish the results here.

Comment: You're right, of course.  But one other reason that people like to commit frequently is so that they don't have to rollback (which can itself take a long time) and start over from the very beginning if the process errors.  But rather than committing, OP should look into `ALTER SESSION ENABLE RESUMABLE` if that is a consideration.

Comment: I test a plan using cursor . in this plan insert command has been committed every 1 million rows. the time of process goes long. DO NOT USE CURSOR OR COMMIT BETWEEN INSERT COMMAND.

Done!